# When we breathe through the nose, do we normally make an unvoiced uvular nasal?

Tags: ipa, nasals

I was thinking about what sounds we make when we breathe through our nose. I realized that we make a sound that is very far back, farther than the velar nasal. Do we normally make this sound, and is this the most common phoneme because it happens when we breathe?

Comment: It's not a phoneme if it's not used in speech. We make lots of noises that aren't phonemes.

Comment: But anyhow do we make voiceless uvular nasals when we breathe out through our nose?

Comment: Only if we involve the uvula. Since it's usually closed with the velic flap during nasal breathing, it wouldn't be a uvular nasal. That would require an open mouth to provide a resonant chamber for the uvular nasal.

Answer (score 2):

"Unvoiced uvular nasal" refers to a particular kind of language sound, just as "unvoiced bilabial fricative" (=[φ]) does. The physical action of articulating [φ] is similar to how you blow out a candle, but when you blow out a candle, you don't produce [φ] (for one, you don't blow when you speak, but youu do for a candle-blowing-action). Likewise, breathing through your nose is not the same as producing [N̥], but it is similar in terms of the physical state of the vocal tract. However, [N̥] has additional back-of-the-mouth constrictions of the pharynx and tongue that are not part of nose-breathing.